# IE8 no longer allows access to individual characters without using substr function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I used to access individual characters of a string using string[n].

But when I do this in IE8 it always returns undefined when I do this.

I can use string.substr(n, 1) to do the same thing, but the syntax is much longer.  Why did they do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That form of character access is not part of the ECMAScript standard, but is implemented by some VMs. I would go with charAt as RoBorg suggested and avoid unstandardized features.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`string.charAt(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) - I'm not sure when `string[n]` became valid or why it's been removed.

Edit: I've tested in IE 6 and 7 and `string[n]` didn't work in any of them.

Comment: Link is down at the moment :/